# How can I increase the A2DP bitpool on Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, linux-mint, wireless-headset

I recently bought a Bluetooth headset (Philips SHB4000), and got it to stop sounding like a phone after I told Linux (Mint) to use A2DP rather than HSP/HFP.

However, there's still an annoying crackling sound that I'd like to get rid of.

Some googling suggested that the "bitpool size" might be to blame, but I couldn't find any info on how to increase it on Linux. I know it's probably in some config file somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: [This mailing list thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.bluez.kernel/17075) looks promising -- it mentions setting bitpool size in `~/.asoundrc`, which is described [on the Alsa wiki](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your problem is:
set A2DP bitpool size in ~/.asoundrc file
the maximum size depends on the device you want to use.
You can take a look at http://vlsd.blogspot.nl/2013/11/bluetooth-headphones-and-arch-linux.html.
Hope it helps.